# Вставные предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли оформлены вставные предложения (особенно интересуют запятые перед тире)?

Как ни странно, у нас в городе подорожали даже пиломатериалы, хотя лес и пилорамы находятся в области (все пытаются получить сиюминутную выгоду), но пока тотального роста цен нет.

Как ни странно, у нас в городе подорожали даже пиломатериалы, хотя лес и пилорамы находятся в области, — все пытаются получить сиюминутную выгоду, — но пока тотального роста цен нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, всё вполне корректно, запятые и тире поставлены в соответствии с условиями постановки. Это не единый знак препинания, потому что не перед главным в сложноподчинённом, а первая запятая отделяет конец придаточного уступительного, а вторая необходима перед противопоставлением с НО, тире выделяют вставную конструкцию.

Но я бы выбрала первый вариант, где скобки упрощают громоздкую конструкцию, делают понятной и не вызывают вопросов.

Comment: Спасибо большое!